# Is it possible to programmatically change the color of a vector image from a XAML WPF Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, vector, resources

I'm creating a XAML WPF Resource Dictionary with vector glyphs (DrawingImage) for our application. They are all the same color. Some areas of the UI require different color icons.

Ideally, I would like to keep the dictionary without duplicates/variations and I want to see if it's possible for developers to override the color programmatically.

Images are set by

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource icon_checkmark}"></Image>
```

**Example of a glyph:**

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="icon_checkmark">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource icon_color}" Geometry="F1 M 15.3347,40C 14.3093,40 13.3413,39.528 12.7093,38.7213L 0.708,23.388C -0.426667,21.9387 -0.170667,19.8427 1.27867,18.708C 2.72933,17.5747 4.824,17.8293 5.95867,19.2787L 15.3347,31.2573L 36.708,3.94534C 37.844,2.496 39.936,2.24 41.388,3.37467C 42.8373,4.50933 43.092,6.60534 41.9587,8.05467L 17.96,38.7213C 17.328,39.528 16.36,40 15.3347,40 Z "/>
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

Comment: You might only keep the geometries in your resource dictionary and use them with Path controls.